# Haskell & Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, haskell

I reviewed different means for connecting to oracle db from Haskell. I found one, ODBC. Ideally, I wish to use an oracle client to connect.  Do you know any other way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

[Takusen](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Takusen) provides direct access to Oracle DBs, however, the ODBC-enabled libraries, such as [HDBC](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HDBC-odbc) may be easier to use.

Look on [Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pkg-list.html#cat:database) for more options.

Comment: i installed Takusen. But the Oracle modules i did not find

Comment: I  think you have to compile it with a -foracle or some thing like it flag.

Answer (score 3):

I have written an Oracle driver for HDBC largely inspired by Takusen and HSQL. It uses Oracle's OCI library for interfacing with the database.

I consider it experimental for now. But if you want to try it, you can find a darcs repo for it at http://thiagoarrais.com/repos/hdbc-oracle/.

Comment: Have you used this on linux, or only on windows? I'm playing with it now, and having some trouble getting everything to link...

Comment: On linux, the "Extra-Libraries" line of the .cabal file should list `clntsh` rather than `oci`. By the way, thanks for the lib!